# Restrict items to select by extension in Sitecore8 Internal Link Field

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I have an Internal Link Field in a custom template in Sitecore 8. I want the user to use the Link Field to ONLY select a (say) PDF File from the Media Library. When clicking on "Insert Link" the Media Library pops up, scoped to the node I set in the DataSource Field. In here, I want the user to only see PDF files.

Is there any chance this can be done with the Internal Link Field?

Or maybe some other way around that problem? I don't want to have a custom Field Validation that prevents the user from saving the actual item. I'd rather have the user not selecting any "wrong" files for the field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out-of-the box you will not be able to do this. You have a few options that I can think of right now:

- Change the field type to treelist (or treelistEx) and use `Datasource=/sitecore/media library/....&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=Pdf,media folder&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=Pdf` as datasource - your datasource will do exactly what you want but your editors will be able to select multiple pdf's (this can be checked with validation but you wanted to avoid that)
- Change field type to droplink and use `query:/sitecore/media library/....//*[@@templatename='Pdf']` as datasource - now they can only select one, but you get a flat list of items and that might be not that easy to work with
- Create a custom field type for a link with datasource: this is more work but could give you exactly what you want and it seems like it has [been done before](https://mickeyrahman.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/sitecore-general-link-field-with-source-query/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will probably look into the third option since I don't want to use a TreeList for a single file selection. DropList would be fine, but I would miss out a lot of usability for the actual user when not using the media library. Also thanks for the link :)